# Changing jquery with respect to screen sizes

Tags: jquery

I am using slick slider and I want to make it responsive but I'm unable to do so.

I tried to do the task by these two ways which I found on internet but it didn't work for me Here is my code,That's One way I found

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 if(window.width() <= 320)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else if(window.width() <= 480)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else if(window.width() <= 542)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else if(window.width() <= 768)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else{
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

});
```

That's the other way using resize function

```
 $(document).resize(function(e){
 if(window.width() <= 320)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else if(window.width() <= 480)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else if(window.width() <= 542)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else if(window.width() <= 768)
 {
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

 else{
     $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
  });
 }

});
```

What i want is slider show 5 posts on large screen, 4 posts on medium screen, 3 posts on small screen and 2 posts on extra small screen, Please help me where i'm wrong or if any better approach than this I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: Have you tried changing `window.width()` to `$(window).width()`

Comment: yes but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this snippet. The main two problems were that you user `window.width()` instead of `$(window).width()` and that you need to 'unslick' the slider first before you can 'reslick' it.

Beware though before you can 'unslick' the slider, it needs to be 'slicked' first. That's why I use the `$(document).ready()` to give it the default `slick()` and after that I call `$(window).resize();` to 'slick' it to the right proportion

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('div.slick').slick();
  $(window).resize();
});


$(window).resize(function(e){
  if($(window).width() <= 320)
  {
    $('div.slick').slick('unslick');
    $('div.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
  }

  else if($(window).width() <= 480)
  {
    $('div.slick').slick('unslick');
    $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
  }

  else if($(window).width() <= 542)
  {
    $('div.slick').slick('unslick');
    $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
  }

  else if($(window).width() <= 768)
  {
    $('div.slick').slick('unslick');
    $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
  }

  else{
    $('div.slick').slick('unslick');
    $('.slick').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slick">
  <div>your content1</div>
  <div>your content2</div>
  <div>your content3</div>
  <div>your content4</div>
  <div>your content5</div>
  <div>your content6</div>
  <div>your content7</div>
  <div>your content8</div>
  <div>your content9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sameedulhassan No problem! Might I suggest looking into a [switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) for the window width instead of all the `if/elseif` statements.